# Using Spring Kafka and Java, how to get the latest message offset in a topic?

Tags: java, spring-kafka

I'd like to know the latest message offset waiting to be consumed in a Kafka topic, so I can compare with the current message consumed offset. The goal is once I reach that latest I will stop the consumption of any message coming later.

Searching for similar questions, no one is meeting the same circumstances
or if so it is using apache Kafka

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<Integer, String> cf = new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);
Consumer<Integer, String> consumer = cf.createConsumer();

consumer.position(new TopicPartition(topic, partition));
```

You really create a native `KafkaConsumer` and use its `position()`:

```
 * Get the offset of the <i>next record</i> that will be fetched (if a record with that offset exists).
 * This method may issue a remote call to the server if there is no current position for the given partition.
 * <p>
 * This call will block until either the position could be determined or an unrecoverable error is
 * encountered (in which case it is thrown to the caller).
```

But you still get a gain of reusing configurations via Spring for Kafka API.

Comment: Thanks Artem, I will give this a try. For now I have set a timer for each time I consume a message and cancel it in the following message to be consumed and so on. The timer will execute the task I am waiting for if no message arriving for a specific time

Comment: Not sure how it is related to the `position` subject, but what you describe is a part of the `ListenerContainerIdleEvent`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/_reference.html#idle-containers